# Jquery error --> Permission denied to access property document

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery in my web application and working with an iframe to show an application hosted on the same websphere server. Through the following code I am able to achieve an automatic login into the web application showing in the iframe....

JSP

```
<form:form id="posManagerLoginForm" 
    action="${posManagerUrl}" 
    target="posManagerFrame" 
    method="post" 
    class="ym-form whitenopadding">

<input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="myusername" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="mypassword" />

</form:form>

<div class="ym-gbox">
    <iframe id="posManagerFrame" name="posManagerFrame" class="posManagerFrame"></iframe>                                          
</div>
```

JS

```
$().ready(function() {   
    $("#posManagerLoginForm").submit();
});
```

So far so good but now I am now trying to change the JS to be able to get the content in the iframe after the login has happened i.e. after form submit.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#posManagerLoginForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();        
            this.submit();          
            var iframe = $("#posManagerFrame").contents();        
            return true;
    });
    $("#posManagerLoginForm").trigger("submit");   
});
```

As you can see I register a function for form submit and try and trigger the function on load. I have two issues....

1. I get a **Permission denied to access property document** error when trying to get contents of iframe.
2. While the .trigger("submit") statement does cause my function to execute, it appears to submit the form and then trigger the function. I am trying not to submit the form until the this.submit() statement.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

I have posted a couple of questions already this morning. Sorry about that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't think you can ever get content of iFrmae. I've used window.postMessage in the past. There is a spec on it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage You will need a fallback though.

Comment: thanks for your input. For some stupid reason we have to support ie6 at my company so I don't think that is an option for me. My ultimate aim to be able to intercept the event where the user clicks on the logout button in the iframe because on logout the browser is closed. So as an alternative I might try to see if I can intercept the close browser event and somehow check if the request is coming from the iframe.

Comment: I just don't think that is possible as Alex stated below. It's just a permissions thing. Otherwise I could iFrame in your bank website and capture anything I wanted from that iFrame. Just not allowed unless you control both pages and I think only with postMessage. You could go a round about way (if you control both pages) to push the content from the iframe to a temp file, poll from the parent page looking for the temp file, and then grab it once it exists. But not exactly ideal or smooth.

Answer (score 2):

This is forbidden due to cross domain origin. You can only get content of iframe from the same domain you are on.

Comment: When you say cross domain what does that mean? Because both my applications are deployed in the same Websphere server.

Comment: @Richie, by cross domain I mean that the src of the iFrame and the domain the response of your page came from. So lets say the response on the page came from the localhost. It includes an iFrame. The src on the iframe is pointing to facebook.com, Thats cross domain.